# Wifi connected with good signal but internet stops working until reconnect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I realize this is a common question.. but the answers dont seem as common sadly.

I have a TPLink WR1043ND v1 router, which has been holding up pretty well given its age. However since the last one year, some devices in my house are having a recurring problem. It works fine most of the time, but suddenly the internet will stop working, and will not resume forcing a disconnect reconnect to get it working. Throughout this time the wifi signal indicator and other indicators of wifi strength and presence of internet show no issues. As luck would have it my wife's phone is one of the devices :P.

This issue has been happening over the course of the last one year, through DDWrt and openWRT and random attempts to tweak stuff on each.

The phone is the main victim, but she is having the same issue with laptops as well. This error happens multiple times a day, and thus doesnt appear to be DHCP issue, since im pretty sure the DHCP lease time is much longer than hours.

Is this a sign that the router is dying? Or fixable?

Comment: There really isn't much infomation in your question to go on (and that's likely why you can't find an issue that matches). Can you ping the router? Can you ping out to the internet via an IP address (indicating a DNS issue) - does the DHCP Lease actually expire? (Don't guess, check)

Comment: Also the router is so old! Maybe it's time for some new hardware? :-)